# Why does casting inside a windowing function return an incorrect type?

Tags: google-bigquery

The following sample query combining windowing functions and casting does not produce the expected result:

```
SELECT
  visitorid,
  LEAD(TIMESTAMP(date)) OVER (PARTITION BY visitorid) AS ts
FROM (
  SELECT
    "000001" AS visitorid,
    "2014-04-28" AS date,
    INTEGER(21) AS metric),
  (
  SELECT
    "000001" AS visitorid,
    "2014-04-29" AS date,
    INTEGER(42) AS metric),
  (
  SELECT
    "000002" AS visitorid,
    "2014-04-28" AS date,
    INTEGER(84) AS metric)
ORDER BY
  visitorid ASC
```

Given the nature of the lead function, only the first row will contain entries for both visitorid and ts.

[image: The result]

If we look closer at the column ts, it's type is an integer instead of a timestamp. That is, I expected to see "2014-04-29 00:00:00 UTC" rather than "1398729600000000" in the first row of ts. Does this mean that casting is incompatible with windowing functions like LEAD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=374&can=1&q=lag) that timestamps get converted to integers with some window functions, although when I filed that report, `lead` was among the functions that worked for me.

You can convert the integer back to timestamp in a superselect. The issue is solved in the [standard sql dialect](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) that was released as alpha yesterday. (It doesn't seem to be available for me yet.)

Comment: If you can't enable the query directly in the UI, you can "hack" it by creating a job with the API where you disable the useLegacySql attribute. It worked for me as the field magically appeared in the UI afterwards.

Comment: You need to download fresh Cloud SDK (version > 107) to get "bq query --nouse_legacy_sql ..." flag working. UI changes should be available to everybody, maybe you need to refresh browser caches ?

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky It is working for me now. As discussed here, browser cache was not the issue https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=448

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in oulenz answer, the standard SQL dialect fixes this issue and here's an adapted version of the sample query:

```
SELECT
  visitorid,
  LEAD(CAST(date AS TIMESTAMP)) OVER (PARTITION BY visitorid ORDER BY visitorid ASC) AS ts
FROM (
  SELECT
    AS STRUCT "000001" AS visitorid,
    "2014-04-28" AS date,
    21 AS metric UNION ALL
  SELECT
    AS STRUCT "000001" AS visitorid,
    "2014-04-29" AS date,
    42 AS metric UNION ALL
  SELECT
    AS STRUCT "000002" AS visitorid,
    "2014-04-28" AS date,
    84 AS metric )
```

The result is as expected:

[image: New SQL Reference result]